# ActionBarSherlock is the correct choice?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm looking to make a layout where there are tabs at the top.  The tabs would be:
Friends, Requests and Search.  I would like the Friends and Requests to be buttons as they need to be read where as I would like the Search to be the generic magnify glass.  I have had this working with a fairly generic setup however the SearchView is squished and can't be read.

Would ActionBarSherlock allow me to accomplish this?

Is ActionBarSherlock capable of creating such action bars below the main actionbar at the top of the screen?

If it isn't what would be the best way to accomplish this kind of view?

Cheers,

Jake

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK now offers a native solution for the ActionBar pattern. It's available through the **v7 appcompat library**. So, there's no need to integrate Action Bar Sherlock on you app. 
All the info you need and related links can be found at [Developer Android Site](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ActionBarSherlock is to bring the Action Bar to older (pre-Honeycomb) devices. If that isn't a requirement, you don't need ABS and I recommend not using it. Here's some documentation on using the latest APIs to do what you need:

- [Tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)
- [Search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used ABS before and it is completely OK to go with it. In case you don't have any constraint to use only ABS it is always better to go with Android's action bar